# Complete arrays with different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm receiving different json objects from some websites. 
This objects usually don't look the same.

How can I do to add the missing keys on every position of the json object ?

Here you have an example to represent the object given

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->a1 = ["name"=>"John","age"=>"27","phone"=>"5566634"];
$data->a2 = ["name"=>"Mark","age"=>"38","gender"=>"Male"];
```

And that's the Desired output:

```
$data->a1 = ["name"=>"John","age"=>"27","phone"=>"5566634", "gender"=>"unknown"];
$data->a2 = ["name"=>"Mark","age"=>"38","phone"=>"unknown", "gender"=>"Male"];
```

I just want to have the same keys on every array

What I've tried is to foreach all the object and save all the existing keys on `$arraykeys`. Then foreach again all the object checking if the current
        key is inside the `$arraykeys` created but this is really slow with big json objects.

What i've tried so far to get all the keys:

```
$arraykeys = [];
foreach ( $data as $item ) {
    foreach ( $item as $key => $value ) {
        if (! array_key_exists($key, $arraykeys)){
            $arraykeys[$key] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

but don't know how to complete the arrays having all the keys. How can I solve this problem ?

**Note:** the object may have `n` positions and more keys. This is just an example. Ideally the keys will be on the same order on every array.

Comment: Is "arraykeys" known as a predefined list?

Comment: no, this is just an example, but there are more keys, like email, address, etc. Also may be more in future. That's why I need to get all the keys...

Comment: @KrBm https://eval.in/581163 You can use your solution to build key array. It works

Comment: @KrBm or a little simplify the 2nd loop if you init arraykeys with 'unknown` - https://eval.in/581178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended solution using `call_user_func_array`, `array_replace_recursive`, `array_keys`, `array_fill_keys` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->a1 = ["name"=>"John","age"=>"27","phone"=>"5566634"];
$data->a2 = ["name"=>"Mark","age"=>"38","gender"=>"Male"];
$data->a3 = ["name"=>"Mark","age"=>"38","gender"=>"Male", "email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "address"=>"Jack London st. 102"];
$data->a4 = ["name"=>"John","age"=>"30","gender"=>"Male"];

// getting the array containing all possible keys
$keys = call_user_func_array('array_replace_recursive', (array) $data);

// filling predefined list of keys with "unknown" value
$keys = array_fill_keys(array_keys($keys), "unknown");

foreach ($data as &$prop) {
    $prop = array_merge($keys, $prop);
}

print_r($data);
```

The output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [a1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [age] => 27
            [phone] => 5566634
            [gender] => unknown
            [email] => unknown
            [address] => unknown
        )

    [a2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mark
            [age] => 38
            [phone] => unknown
            [gender] => Male
            [email] => unknown
            [address] => unknown
        )

    [a3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mark
            [age] => 38
            [phone] => unknown
            [gender] => Male
            [email] => myemail@gmail.com
            [address] => Jack London st. 102
        )

    [a4] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [age] => 30
            [phone] => unknown
            [gender] => Male
            [email] => unknown
            [address] => unknown
        )
)
```

Comment: looks like the `phone` is just on the first array, how can i fix this ?

Comment: @KrBm sorry, just one moment. There will be an update

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform this with many fields, you can do the following :

```
<?php
$defaultArray = [
    'name'   => 'unknown',
    'age'    => 'unknown',
    'gender' => 'unknown',
    'phone'  => 'unknown',
];

foreach ( $data as $item ) {
    $item = array_merge($defaultArray, $item);
}
```

It will replace the unknown values by the values that are present in your array.